# How can i make a continuous python slider discrete?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Recently I have been developing a code to create a function approximation through Bernstein's polynomial.
The problem i have is that I want to represent the Bernstein's polynomial for different values for 'n'. I found an example on Matplotlib how to make sliders so I copied to see if it worked with my function. The result is that for a starting 'n' value it works but as soon as I change it, it stops working because the slider is only using integers but if you move it the function changes as if 'n' could have any value for an interval. The code:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons


def f(x):
    return np.abs(x)

def fac(x):
    return np.math.factorial(x)

def ecuacion(n,k):
    result = ((fac(n)) / (fac(k) * fac(n - k))) * ((x + 1) ** k * (1 - x) ** (n - k)) / (2 ** n) * f(2 * k / n - 1)
    return result

def bernstein(x, k, n):
    #p = ((fac(n)) / (fac(k) * fac(n - k))) * ((x + 1) ** k * (1 - x) ** (n - k)) / (2 ** n) * f(2 * k / n - 1)
    resultado = 0
    for k in range(0,n+1):
        resultado = ecuacion(n,k) + resultado
    return resultado

axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.001)

freq_0 = 3

# Draw the initial plot
# The 'line' variable is used for modifying the line later
[line] = ax.plot(x, bernstein(x,0,2), linewidth=2, color='red')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

# Add two sliders for tweaking the parameters

# Define an axes area and draw a slider in it
amp_slider_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
amp_slider = Slider(amp_slider_ax, 'n', 2, 50, valinit=2)

# Draw another slider
freq_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
freq_slider = Slider(freq_slider_ax, 'Freq', 3, 30.0, valinit=6)

# Define an action for modifying the line when any slider's value changes
def sliders_on_changed(val):
    line.set_ydata(bernstein(x,amp_slider.val, freq_slider.val))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
amp_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)
freq_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)

# Add a button for resetting the parameters
reset_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
reset_button = Button(reset_button_ax, 'Reset', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')
def reset_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    freq_slider.reset()
    amp_slider.reset()
reset_button.on_clicked(reset_button_on_clicked)

#Add a set of radio buttons for changing color
# color_radios_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15])
# color_radios = RadioButtons(color_radios_ax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
# def color_radios_on_clicked(label):
#     line.set_color(label)
#     fig.canvas.draw_idle()
# color_radios.on_clicked(color_radios_on_clicked)

plt.show()
```